# Sifr doesn't work in FF 3

Tags: firefox, sifr

When I check [this site](http://www.dewereldvandevn.nl/) in IE and FF. I found out that sifr works in ie but not in FF.

You can see the difference in the h1 tags

Can anyone tell me what I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using sIFR 2.0.2 on that page. If you insist on using sIFR 2, you'll have to use 2.0.7 for it to work with Flash 10.